# TortoiseGit create a patch on Win7

Tags: git, tortoise-git

First time I used TortoiseGit to control version and I needed to create a patch (after my first commit). This is what I tried to do.

① Right click on base folder -> TortoiseGit -> create patch serial...

③ Got a window, set output directory

③ Set version to "Since: `master`"

④ Click OK

[image]

And previewed this message

[image]

It says success, but I can't find where the patch file.

Did I do it wrong? Otherwise what is the path of the the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format patch dialog allows you to create a patch serial starting from a specific version to your HEAD. THe patch files will be created in the root of the working tree.

In the picture you selected "master" as the starting point. If your current HEAD is also master, then no patches will be created at all. You should consider to select "Number of commits" for the amount of patches to create OR select a commit range.